# Connecting to LAN webserver through a tunnel on LAN node?

Tags: networking, lan, tunnel, wan

So I have work computer that has access to LAN webserver that is not accessible from WAN. Now I want to plant some kind of silent software in my computer to allow me to tunnel to said server through my home computer. Work computer is left online and has connection to the internet.

How do I go about doing this with a silent software? Can it be easily programmed? If so, can I get some pointers?

Comment: Why does it have to be silent? If your work does not allow it, then you should refrain from this activity. Is it against your IT policy? If so, can you get in trouble or fired for it? The best way is to ask permission and ask your IT what the best method is.

Answer (score 2):

The term you're looking for is "VPN" ([Virtual Private Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)).

You setup a VPN server at work, and then use your home OS's VPN connection facilities to connect to it so that your home computer is then joined to the work network.  This will allow you do access work resources, as you are now part of the work LAN.

Which VPN solution you choose is up to you, and since you haven't chosen one there's not much more instruction I can offer.

Discuss it with your work's IT staff and get them involved, as trying to implement this without their assistance may put you out of a job for violating their security policies. ;)